# Concentration around the median implies concentration around the mean

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, high-dimensional, probability-inequalities

Let $M$ denote the median of a function $f(X)$ that is Lipschitz continuous with $\left \| f \right \|_{Lip}=1$. I am trying to show that if $\left \| f(X)-M \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\leq C$, then $\left \| f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\leq C$, where $\psi_{2}$ is the sub-gaussian norm. I understand that the inverse is true due to the fact that the median minimizes the $L_{1}$ norm which is bounded by the sub-gaussian norm.

For this direction I thought about using

\begin{align}
\left \| f(X)-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}=\left \| f(X)-M+M-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\\
\leq\left \| f(X)-M \right \|_{\psi_{2}}+\left \| M-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}\\
\leq C+\left \| M-\mathbb{E}f(X) \right \|_{\psi_{2}}
\end{align}

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Do you need the same $C$ in the two bounds? That is, are you trying to show $\|f(X)-Ef(X)\|\leq \|f(X)-M\|$?

Comment: By "the inverse is true," do you mean "the converse is true?"  If the converse is true, the statement can't be true unless $\mathbb{E}f(x) = M$, it seems to me, as both statements together amount to $||f(x) - \mathbb{E}f(x)|| \leq ||f(x)-M||$ and $||f(x)-M|| \leq ||f(x)-\mathbb{E}f(x)|$|, implying $||f(x) - \mathbb{E}f(x)|| = ||f(x)-M||$.

Comment: Also, what role do $f$ and $X$ play here? That is, would the question be the same if you just replaced $f(X)$ by $Y$, and if not, why not?